# Java_Home configuration

Tags: java-home

I installed Java 21 and Maven but when I run Maven this description appears
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

In my java_home it looks like this
Java_Home c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

I already uninstalled Java and Maven and installed them again and it didn't help. Can someone help me?
windows10

I already uninstalled Java and Maven and installed them again and it didn't help.
I already rewrote JAVA_Home and nothing.

Can someone help me?
windows10

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing to an older version of Java (jdk1.8.0_65) instead of the Java 21 version you have installed. To resolve this issue, you need to update the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to your Java 21 installation.

Here's a guide:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html

The JAVA_HOME variable should point to something like *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21* (confirm this directory's name).